# Does 'this' refer to three clauses?

Tags: reference, antecedents, demonstrative-pronouns

Does ***this*** refer to all these:

- executives regularly combine business meetings with meals
- lobbyists invite politicians to attend receptions, lunches, and dinners
- major state occasions almost always involve an elaborate banquet

Or, just the last clause? The word ***diplomacy***, at least to me, makes it ambiguous.

> Countless studies have shown that the positive emotional state induced
> by a good meal  naturally enhances our receptiveness to be persuaded.
> It triggers an instinctive desire to repay the provider. This is why
> executives regularly combine business meetings with meals, why
> lobbyists invite politicians to attend receptions, lunches, and
> dinners, and why major state occasions almost always involve an
> elaborate banquet. Churchill called ***this*** “dining diplomacy,” and
> sociologists have confirmed that this principle is a potent
> motivator across all human cultures. As a lifelong politician, I have
> witnessed “dining diplomacy” firsthand, sharing meals with royalty,
> presidents, diplmats, and business leaders across the globe.

[The Course of History: Ten Meals That Changed the World](https://%20https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=RupzDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT8&lpg=PT8&dq=is%20a%20clinically%20proven%20fact.%20Food%20is%20the%20original%20mind-controlling%20drug.%20Every%20time%20we%20eat,%20we%20bombard%20our%20brains%20with%20a%20feast%20of%20chemicals,%20triggering%20an%20explosive%20hormonal&source=bl&ots=cuUBx2qdGa&sig=ACfU3U1k-Ix2Ch_hp5-oqjjj1bgiSqCmAA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ2O3A9LX-AhUNQ94KHdisDSoQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=is%20a%20clinically%20proven%20fact.%20Food%20is%20the%20original%20mind-controlling%20drug.%20Every%20time%20we%20eat%2C%20we%20bombard%20our%20brains%20with%20a%20feast%20of%20chemicals%2C%20triggering%20an%20explosive%20hormonal&f=false)

Comment: It is self-explanatory: **Churchill called this “dining diplomacy**,” and sociologists have confirmed that this principle

Comment: Yes, _this_ refers to the three 'whys'.

Comment: Sorry, Lambie. I made a mistake, so I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically (syntactically) ambiguous, so the reader must use his or her knowledge of the situation (semantics) to figure out what "this" refers to. I doubt that Churchill (a nearly lifelong politician) was talking about executives. It's not quite so strange that he might have been talking about lobbyists, although I find that a bit unlikely, too. It's certainly possible that he was talking about major state occasions, although it would be a bit unusual to talk about the third clause without the previous two.

Instead, I think that "this" refers to the principle of reciprocity more generally: One person provides a meal, and the other person feels obligated to return the favor. (Later, the sentence even refers to it as "this principle".) That idea is described in the first two sentences of the paragraph. That means that the pronoun shares an antecedent with "this" at the beginning of the third sentence, and it makes sense that both instances of "this" would refer to the same antecedent.

Answer (score 1):

The use of words like "this" to refer to elements of the text itself is called [deixis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis) and is a generally interesting topic in the study of meaning.

My understanding of this construction is that the author gives three examples of something, then "this" refers to the category of meaning that is exemplified by these three examples. The three examples are of the combination of a meal with some kind of negotiation or meeting. So my understanding is that Churchill referred to the pattern of having a meal during negotiations as "dining diplomacy".

There isn't a specific rule of English being applied here.  This kind of deixis can occur in all languages.